# Function for any integer series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

For any series of integers S = [a,b,c,...,n,...] (finite or infinite), does at least one function F such as F(X) = S[X], X integer, exist?

Update: a function that doesn't directly depend on S (nor have S as its definition)

eg: S=[1,2,4,8,16,32...], an example for F would be F(n) = n**2

Comment: For finite, yes. You can just assume that the function is $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots + a_n x^n$, where $n$ is the number of terms that you have minus one, and solve for $a_k$. It becomes a linear system of equations.

Comment: @Arthur any kind of mathematical function that doesn't depend directly on S

Comment: @MattiP. OP is not asking for 'nice' functions. You can always define $F$ to be $0$ for non-integers.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy okay, well, I was just giving an example.

Comment: @toto If you want $F(X)=S(X)$ you cannot make $F$ independent of $S$.

Comment: Function $\ne$ formula...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it's S[X] such as *index* (maybe this is not the correct notation for it)

Comment: I get the impression that what you want is a way to create a *formula* for the sequence without having to explicitly encode the sequence's actual elements into it.  For this, unfortunately, I have bad news: most sequences are uncomputable: for all but a vanishingly small (and yet, somehow, still infinitely large) set of sequences, there is no formula that exists other than the sequence itself (plus a small 'formula' that just says 'look at this infinitely long list')

Comment: @DanUznanski sure, the answer can be 'no' but is there any formal theorem or proof that demonstrate this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

The function $F: A\to\Bbb Z$ where $A$ is $\Bbb N$ if $S$ is infinite, and $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ if $S$ has $n$ elements, given by
$$
F(X) = \text{The $X$th element of $S$}
$$
is well defined.

Comment: This might sound... Facile: that a function requires so little to be a thing that the answer to "can this be described by a function" is, in this case, "yes, by describing it exactly as you already did", but this is a consequence of how we've needed to simplify and generalize what a function actually is in order for this definition to actually work all the time.  For a sense of how this happened, Wikipedia's page on it is a pretty decent starting point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_function_concept